# Do the .NET XML documentation files need to be deployed to production?

Tags: c#, .net

I think there is a benefit to deploying PDB files to production, it seems to affect error reporting.

Now, is there any benefit to deploying the the large XML documentation files to a production server, (those files like foo.xml that appears along side foo.pdb and foo.dll)

They're consuming FTP time and I'll like to kick them out of deployment packages if they are not providing any benefit.

(They would still exist in source control of course)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short No.

They are mostly used by developers (think intellisense...). And should in general be deployed with the assemblies when used by other developers as libraries.

I would also avoid adding them to source control. (the same goes for dlls and pdbs) They are generated from source on compile so there is no need for them to be in source control.

Answer (score 1):

There is a case where you'd like them to be deployed, it's for example cases where you expose Swagger in production (or staging) and would like the XML comments content (`<summary>, <remarks>`) be included in the Swagger Doc

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
 {   
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "YourApiName.xml");
    c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
 }
```